.htaccess 301 redirect with # hashtag in the URL
i need to redirect a single url with a # within it. For some reason the system generated this.
Old URL: https://testurl.com/part1#/part0229452
New URL: https://testurl.com/part1
I think that the 'simple way' is not working beause of the #, but it is impossible to remove the # (already changed the URL) but i need the redirect to keep Google working.
Thanks

The fragment portion of the URL is not send to the server in the first place, so you can not rewrite based on it from the server side either.
